# Could not translate host name <DATABASE_URL>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, docker, heroku

I'm sorry, but I'm not very good at English.

I'm trying to run a Rails app on heroku.
I'm trying to migrate the database using ridgepole, but I can't resolve the hostname of postgres.

Specifically, I am getting the following error

```
>>> heroku run bundle exec ridgepole -c config/database.yml -f db/Schemafile --apply

[ERROR] could not translate host name <DATABASE_URL> to address: Name or service not known
```

I have enabled the Heroku Postgres add-on.
I tried to resolve the host name (pg_isready) from my local environment (MacOS), but it gave me a "no response".

```
>>> pg_isready -h <DATABASE_URL>

<DATABASE_URL> - no response
```

I would like to ask for your help.

Comment: How shall anybody say something meaningful to that without knowing the URL?

Comment: Why do you think you need Ridgepole? The normal way to do this would be to create the production database from the migrations in your app.